# Bipartite Graph

Tags: graphs, edge

The edges of my graph are overlapping, is there a way to have some distance between them and also how to color a specific edge?

```
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
  every node/.style={draw,circle},
  ssnode/.style={fill=myblue},
  fsnode/.style={fill=mygreen},
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=-1pt,text width=1.75cm},
  ->,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt
]

% the vertices of Slots
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=1.5mm]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,8}
  \node[ssnode,on chain] (s\i) [label=left: \i] {};
\end{scope}

% the vertices of Flights
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-0.5cm,start chain=going below,node distance=1.5mm]
\foreach \i in {$f_{2}$,$f_{5}$,$f_{6}$,$f_{7}$,$f_{8}$}
  \node[fsnode,on chain] (f\i) [label=right: \i] {};
\end{scope}

% the set Slots
\node [myblue,fit=(s1) (s8),label=above:$Slots$] {};
% the set Flights
\node [mygreen,fit=(f$f_{2}$) (f$f_{8}$),label=above:$Flights$] {};

% the edges

\draw (s2) -- (f$f_{2}$);
\draw (s5) -- (f$f_{5}$);
\draw (s6) -- (f$f_{6}$);
\draw (s7) -- (f$f_{7}$);
\draw (s8) -- (f$f_{8}$);
\draw (f$f_{2}$) -- (s1);
\draw (f$f_{5}$) -- (s3);
\draw (f$f_{6}$) -- (s5);
\draw (f$f_{7}$) -- (s5);
\draw (f$f_{8}$) -- (s7);
\draw (s3) -- (f$f_{5}$);
\draw (s1) -- (f$f_{2}$);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There are various techniques to change the position of the `\draw` lines:

1. specify the start and end position in degrees on the node
2. use `yshift` on the start and end node
3. use the `calc` tikzlibrary to add an offset to the start and/or end positions

The first method is to specify the nodes as `(nodename.degrees)` instead of just `(nodename)`, so instead of `(s5)` you use `(s5.45)` for example. In that case you don't start the line at the point closest to the opposing node, but at the position 45 degrees counterclockwise from the start at 0 degrees which is on the right of the node.

The second method specifies a distance to shift the line node in the y position, with the syntax `([yshift=xx unit]nodename)`, in this case for example `([yshift=-25mm]s6)`. This only works if you shift the opposing node with exactly the same amount, so it is not really flexible.

The third method uses the `calc` tikzlibrary to add a coordinate to the node, with the syntax `($(nodename)+(x,y)$)`. This looks a bit complex but it is the most flexible way. Note that this offsets the `shorten =` attribute, so you need to add that back by adding or subtracting a bit from the x coordinate.

The MWE below shows all three methods. Additionally, I simplified the aming of the `(f)` nodes by putting the subscript in the node label instead of in the node names. For the arrows that go both ways from and to a node I simplified by drawing with `[<->]`. This also looks a bit better in terms of overlap.

Coloring an edge is done by putting the color name as an option to the draw command, for example `\draw[red]`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
  every node/.style={draw,circle},
  ssnode/.style={fill=myblue},
  fsnode/.style={fill=mygreen},
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=-1pt,text width=1.75cm},
  ->,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt
]

% the vertices of Slots
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=1.5mm]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,8}
  \node[ssnode,on chain] (s\i) [label=left: \i] {};
\end{scope}

% the vertices of Flights
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-0.5cm,start chain=going below,node distance=1.5mm]
\foreach \i in {2,5,6,7,8}
  \node[fsnode,on chain] (f\i) [label=right: $f_{\i}$] {};
\end{scope}

% the set Slots
\node [myblue,fit=(s1) (s8),label=above:$Slots$] {};
% the set Flights
\node [mygreen,fit=(f2) (f8),label=above:$Flights$] {};

% the edges

\draw[red] (s2) -- (f2);
\draw (s5.45) -- (f5.220);
\draw ([yshift=-25mm]s6) -- ([yshift=-25mm]f6);
\draw (s7) -- (f7);
\draw (s8) -- (f8);
\draw[<->] ($(f2)+(-0.15,0.15)$) -- (s1);
\draw[<->] (f5) -- (s3);
\draw (f6) -- (s5);
\draw (f7) -- (s5);
\draw (f8) -- (s7);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can space the flight nodes out a bit more and change the arrow tip shape. In the example below I used `Latex[width=3pt, length=4pt]`, which requires the library `arrows.meta`. Also, reducing the distance between the two sets improves the arrow angles.

Other changes:

- Use `\itshape` instead of `$...$` for correct spacing.
- I changed the node names to avoid the strange names for the flight nodes.
- Place the direction of the arrows when you draw them instead of using a global setting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {chains, fit, shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
  every node/.style={draw, circle},
  ssnode/.style={fill=myblue},
  fsnode/.style={fill=mygreen},
  every fit/.style={ellipse, draw, inner sep=-1pt, text width=1.75cm},
  >={Latex[width=3pt, length=4pt]}, shorten >= 2pt, shorten <= 2pt
]

% the vertices of Slots
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=1.5mm]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,8}
  \node[ssnode,on chain] (s\i) [label=left: \i] {};
\end{scope}

% the vertices of Flights
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm, yshift=-0.15cm, start chain=going below, node distance=5mm]
\foreach \i in {2,5,6,7,8}
  \node[fsnode, on chain] (f\i) [label=right: $f_{\i}$] {};
\end{scope}

% the set Slots
\node [myblue, fit=(s1) (s8), label=above:\itshape Slots] {};
% the set Flights
\node [mygreen, fit=(f2) (f8), label=above:\itshape Flights] {};

% the edges
\draw[->] (s2) -- (f2);
\draw[->] (s5) -- (f5);
\draw[->] (s6) -- (f6);
\draw[->] (s7) -- (f7);
\draw[->] (s8) -- (f8);
\draw[<->] (f2) -- (s1);
\draw[<->, red] (f5) -- (s3);
\draw[->, orange] (f6) -- (s5);
\draw[->] (f7) -- (s5);
\draw[->] (f8) -- (s7);

\end{tikzpicture}
```